# Python3 Discord Module No Attribute Client

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was handed a Python Discord Message Mass Prune Script in Py3.
But there were a few errors, Prior to this.
It was working before, but now it's giving me some error that
it didn't give me before.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(' ')
    print('Lorem')
    print('ipsum')
    print('dolor')
    print('amet')
    print('sit')
    print('consectetur')
    print('Logged in as:', client.user.name)
    print('UID:',client.user.id) 
    print('Discord version:',discord.__version__)
    print('----------')
    print('Connected to:')
    for server in client.servers:
        print(' -',server.name)

# Define commands
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    if message.author == client.user:
        commands = []
        z = 0
        for index, a in enumerate(message.content):
            if a == " ":
                commands.append(message.content[z:index])
                z = index+1
        commands.append(message.content[z:])
    
        # MASS DELETE OWN MESSAGES
        if commands[0] == 'xc':
            if len(commands) == 1:
                async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=9999):
                    if msg.author == client.user:   
                        try:
                            await client.delete_message(msg)
                        except Exception as x:
                            pass
            elif len(commands) == 2:
                user_id = ''
                for channel in client.private_channels:
                    if commands[1] in str(channel):
                        if str(channel.type) == 'private':
                            user_id = str(channel.id)
                async for msg in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id=user_id),limit=9999):
                    if msg.author == client.user:
                        try:
                            await client.delete_message(msg)
                        except Exception as x:
                            pass
                        
client.run("TOKEN HERE",bot=False)
```

Using Py3 Pip, I installed discord and asyncio (The required modules) needed for the script.
At line 4 (client = discord.Client())
It throws off the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\discord.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client'
```

Answer (score 17):

Your program is called `discord.py`. That is masking the real `discord` module. Call the program something else.

Answer (score 0):

Change your file name from discord.py to another like discord_message.py

AS it is importing discord from your os only